# How to combine multiple dict variables into an array based on regex of dict variable names

Tags: merge, ansible, jinja2

I have multiple dict variables in my inventories that start with 'my_var_*'.  I would like to combine these into an array of dicts named 'my_var'

In my playbook, I'm using 'set_fact:' to create the 'my_var' variable by attempting to pull the matching variables from "hostvars['localhost']" with a select filter and match regex, but join only works on strings.

variables.yml

```
    my_var_1:
        element1: value11
        element2: value12
    my_var_2:
        element1: value21
        element2: value22
```

playbook.yml

```
    - hosts: localhost
      connection: local
      gather_facts: False
      tasks:
        - set_fact:
            my_var: "{{ hostvars['localhost'] | select('match', '^my_var_*') | join(', ' }}"
        - debug:
            msg: "{{ my_var }}"
```

is it possible to join these 'dict' variables into an 'array' like this?

```
    my_var:
      - element1: value11
        element2: value12
      - element1: value21
        element2: value22
```

or possibly even

```
    my_var:
      - name: 1
        element1: value11
        element2: value12
      - name: 2
        element1: value21
        element2: value22
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close, but as you point out, the `join` method on a string is for joining strings.  You want to append lists, which you accomplish with the `+` operator.

There are also a few other issues:

The expression:

```
hostvars['localhost'] | select('match', '^my_var_*')
```

Will produce a list that looks like:

```
[
  "my_var_1",
  "my_var_2"
]
```

...which isn't what you want. You want the *values* of these variables, not the key names.  We can use the `dict2items` filter and the `selectattr` filter to generate the data we want:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: set facts on localhost
      set_fact:
        my_var_1:
            element1: value11
            element2: value12
        my_var_2:
            element1: value21
            element2: value22

- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: merge vars into my_var
      set_fact:
        my_var: "{{ hostvars['localhost']|dict2items|selectattr('key', 'match', '^my_var_')|map(attribute='value')|list }}"

    - name: show content of my_var
      debug:
        var: my_var
```

This will produce the following output:

```
TASK [show content of my_var] ************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "my_var": [
        {
            "element1": "value11", 
            "element2": "value12"
        }, 
        {
            "element1": "value21", 
            "element2": "value22"
        }
    ]
}
```

If you get rid of the `map(attribute='value')` filter, you get:

```
TASK [show content of my_var] *****************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "my_var": [
        {
            "key": "my_var_1", 
            "value": {
                "element1": "value11", 
                "element2": "value12"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "key": "my_var_2", 
            "value": {
                "element1": "value21", 
                "element2": "value22"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This isn't exactly what you ask for as the second option, but it does include both the key name and values.

---

Additional notes:

1. In the above, I've used a separate play running `set_fact` to set the values of these variables, because this solution will only work if the variables are host vars (aka "facts") rather than global variables. You don't show in your question how you're setting these variables so I don't know if this will all work as written.
2. In a regular expression, `*` means "the preceding character zero or more times", so the expression `^my_var_*` would match `my_var`, `my_var_1`, `my_var______________`, `my_varfoo`, and so forth.  You can simply write `^my_var_` to select the variable names in which you're interested (this will select anything that begins with the text `my_var_`).

Comment: Yep, I see what I was doing wrong there with regex.  And I saw dict2items, but didn't see how I could use it.  I see it now!  This works perfectly.  Thank you!!